# Augment sublists in a list of sublists with missing elements as NA

Tags: r, list, na

I have a list of lists (will call them "sublists" to avoid confusion) containing named elements. Not all sublists contain all named elements. I wish to augment sublists with missing elements as `NA`.

Example:

```
l <- list(list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3),
  list(a = 4, b = 5, c = 6),
  list(a = 7, b = 8),
  list(a = 9, c = 10))
```

As can be seen, the 3rd and 4th sublists are missing the `c` and `b` elements respectively. I would like these elements to be augmented as `NA` to these sublists, i.e.:

```
res <- list(list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3),
  list(a = 4, b = 5, c = 6),
  list(a = 7, b = 8, c = NA),
  list(a = 9, b = NA, c = 10))
```

In reality, if this makes it any easier, each sublist is missing only the last `k` elements (i.e. I do not have a situation as in the 4th sublist missing a middle element `b`), but I feel like while we're at it, let's find a generic solution.

UPDATE:
Got 3 great solutions for this specific scenario, where the sublists elements are `int`s. But the elements can be `chr`s, or even lists! E.g.:

```
l <- list(list(a = list(1,2), b = 2, c = 3),
      list(b = 5, c = 6),
      list(a = list(5,6), b = 8),
      list(a = list(7,8), c = 10))
```

The `a` element is a list and should stay that way in the `res` list. If it is missing, I would like an `NA`, as usual:

```
res <- list(list(a = list(1,2), b = 2, c = 3),
  list(a = NA, b = 5, c = 6),
  list(a = list(5,6), b = 8, c = NA),
  list(a = list(7,8), b = NA, c = 10))
```

Comment: Welp, this is turning into a chameleon question so I'm off. Btw, you should also show your desired output for that new input of yours.

Comment: Subsetting a "list" with a "character" can return `NULL` in case of a non existing name -- i.e. a start could be `nms = unique(unlist(lapply(l, names))); lapply(l, "[", nms)` and, then, restore "names" and replace `NULL`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** We can make unique names, then loop through the lists and subset those names. Names that are not in the list will return NULL, those we will assign with `NA`. This should work for all inputs.

```
# data
l <- list(list(a = list(1,2), b = 2, c = 3),
      list(b = 5, c = 6),
      list(a = list(5,6), b = 8),
      list(a = list(7,8), c = 10))

myNames <- unique(unlist(sapply(l, names)))

res <- lapply(l, function(i){
  x2 <- lapply(myNames, function(j){
    x1 <- i[[ j ]]
    if(is.null(x1)){ x1 <- NA}
    x1
    })
  names(x2) <- myNames
  x2
})

# check results
identical(res,
          #expected output
          list(list(a = list(1,2), b = 2, c = 3),
               list(a = NA, b = 5, c = 6),
               list(a = list(5,6), b = 8, c = NA),
               list(a = list(7,8), b = NA, c = 10)))
# [1] TRUE
```

---

**Original:**
We can treat *sublist* as dataframe and rbind with fill on missing columns, then split again:

```
# data:
l <- list(list(a = list(1,2), b = 2, c = 3),
          list(a = list(3,4), b = 5, c = 6),
          list(a = list(5,6), b = 8),
          list(a = list(7,8), c = 10))

library(dplyr)

# convert to dataframe and rbind with fill on missing columns
x <- bind_rows(lapply(l, as_data_frame))

# then convert it back to list
res <- lapply(split(x, seq(nrow(x))), as.list)

# drop names, we can skip this step if we want to keep names as 1,2,3,4...
names(res) <- NULL

# result
res

# [[1]]
# [[1]]$a
# [1] 1
# 
# [[1]]$b
# [1] 2
# 
# [[1]]$c
# [1] 3
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]]$a
# [1] 4
# 
# [[2]]$b
# [1] 5
# 
# [[2]]$c
# [1] 6
# 
# 
# [[3]]
# [[3]]$a
# [1] 7
# 
# [[3]]$b
# [1] 8
# 
# [[3]]$c
# [1] NA
# 
# 
# [[4]]
# [[4]]$a
# [1] 9
# 
# [[4]]$b
# [1] NA
# 
# [[4]]$c
# [1] 10
```

Comment: Instead of the `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` addition, you could change `data.frame` to `as_tibble`

Comment: @GioraSimchoni Yes, that is I was just about to edit in, thanks.

Comment: Please see UPDATE. The elements need not be `int`s, they can be lists.

Answer (score 0):

Surely there is a better way to do it, but this works with both examples.

res and res2 are the example results you have provided.

l.res and l2.res are the results from the code.

```
l <- list(list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3),
          list(a = 4, b = 5, c = 6),
          list(a = 7, b = 8),
          list(a = 9, c = 10))

res <- list(list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3),
             list(a = 4, b = 5, c = 6),
             list(a = 7, b = 8, c = NA),
             list(a = 9, b = NA, c = 10))

l2 <- list(list(a = list(1,2), b = 2, c = 3),
          list(b = 5, c = 6),
          list(a = list(5,6), b = 8),
          list(a = list(7,8), c = 10))
res2 <- list(list(a = list(1,2), b = 2, c = 3),
            list(a = NA, b = 5, c = 6),
            list(a = list(5,6), b = 8, c = NA),
            list(a = list(7,8), b = NA, c = 10))


#vector with 'column names' to be checked

aux=c("a","b","c")

#function  that check if all sublists have all the elements
#if not, create the element and asign NA value
myfunction<-function(l.list,n.names){

  for(i in 1:length(l.list)){
    for(j in 1:length(n.names)){
      if (n.names[j] %in% names(l.list[[i]]) == FALSE) {
        l.list[[i]][n.names[j]]<-NA
        l.list[[i]]=l.list[[i]][order(unlist(names(l.list[[i]])))]
       }
     }
    }

  return(l.list)
}

#Applying to example 1
l.res<-myfunction(l,aux)

data.frame(l.res) #as a data frame just for comparison purpose
##   a b c a.1 b.1 c.1 a.2 b.2 c.2 a.3 b.3 c.3
## 1 1 2 3   4   5   6   7   8  NA   9  NA  10
data.frame(res)
##   a b c a.1 b.1 c.1 a.2 b.2 c.2 a.3 b.3 c.3
## 1 1 2 3   4   5   6   7   8  NA   9  NA  10


#Applying to example 2
l2.res<-myfunction(l2,aux)

data.frame(l2.res) #as a data frame just for comparison purpose
##   a.1 a.2 b c  a b.1 c.1 a.5 a.6 b.2 c.2 a.7 a.8 b.3 c.3
## 1   1   2 2 3 NA   5   6   5   6   8  NA   7   8  NA  10
data.frame(res2)
##   a.1 a.2 b c  a b.1 c.1 a.5 a.6 b.2 c.2 a.7 a.8 b.3 c.3
## 1   1   2 2 3 NA   5   6   5   6   8  NA   7   8  NA  10
```

Hope it helps.